# Multiple Json response objects in C# - do I need a new namespace for each response object?

Tags: c#, json

I'm new to C# and Json, so please be kind.

I'm using an external API to return some Json responses. I can create a C# object (class) from the Json response (I used on online tool to create the same one I created to make sure I had the right idea).

- Depending on which call I make to the API I get back a different Json response, as expected of course.
  _ I create a C# object (Classes) to match the response.
- I have two responses both containing classes of the **same name**, but with different fields

I have a `.cs` with all the classes stored here in a namespace called `ApiResponses`. However I get the error

> already has a definition for

Here are the two class definitions:

First Json respsonse

```
public class Application
{
    public Page page { get; set; }
    public int members_total { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public DateTime created { get; set; }
    public int members_active { get; set; }
    public IList<undefined> fields { get; set; }
    public IList<Members> members { get; set; }
    public Error error { get; set; }
}
```

Second Json response:

```
public class Application
{
    public int message_id { get; set; }
    public DateTime send_at { get; set; }
    public int recipients { get; set; }
    public double cost { get; set; }
    public int sms { get; set; }
    public Delivery_stats delivery_stats { get; set; }
    public Error error { get; set; }
}
```

What is the best practice way to deal with this?

Should I:

1. create a namespace for each response
2. Combine the attributes in to a single class
3. create another class (wrapper) to put around the duplicated classes (I don't like this idea)

Your thoughts and recommendations are gratefully received.

Ballzy

Combining the two class definitions, is the option I would naturally choose e.g.

```
public class Application
{
    public Page page { get; set; }
    public int members_total { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public DateTime created { get; set; }
    public int members_active { get; set; }
    public IList<undefined> fields { get; set; }
    public IList<Members> members { get; set; }
    public Error error { get; set; }
    public int message_id { get; set; }
    public int recipients { get; set; }
    public double cost { get; set; }
    public int sms { get; set; }
    public Delivery_stats delivery_stats { get; set; }
}
```

As this seems a lot cleaner then creating multiple namespaces.

Is this the right approach for best practice?

Comment: Why do they have to have the same name?

Comment: It's not that they have to, its that they do, because the API that generates them is beyond my controrl.  All I'm doing is creating a matching object so I can use the returned data in the rest of my applicaiton.

Comment: @Ballzy _"because the API that generates them is beyond my control"_ - methinks there's a good principle here: _don't use tools that you can't control_. Also, your editor (VSC? VS?) will have powerful refactoring tools to do things like mass-rename things. Point is: I really can't think of any good reason why you can't rename these types.

Comment: @Ballzy from what i know, the name doesn't have to be same. And you should be able to map the response from your API call i.e. jsonResponse into any object that you want as long as the properties and dataTypes match. you can deserialize the json response into whichever object model you want. I am not a pro in C# but i think its possible. I think there is something called ```JsonConvert.DeserializeObejct<Application1 or Application2>(jsonresponse1 or jsonresponse2);``` The catch is u need to know which response do u want to map into which object.

Comment: *"Depending on which call I make to the API I get back a different Json response"* - can't you differentiate the "expected result" based on "which call I make?" you could also parse the json response into a `JsonObject` and probe around which field it has and deduce which response class fits.

Comment: "have two responses both containing classes of the same name" - it is impossible since Jason string doesn't have and can not  have any classes.

Answer (score 0):

Just say that your 2 WebAPI as the following JSON responses

```
API 1 Response Body: { RandomProperty1: "xyz",  Application: {...} }
API 2 Response Body: { RandomProperty2: false,  Application: {...} }
```

> Depending on which call I make to the API I get back a different Json
> response, as expected of course.

> I have two responses both containing classes of the same name, but
> with different fields

From the above statement, I am guessing that you have a different situation where two responses have the same named property "Application".

As others already hinted, the class name could be different just the property name needs to be matched.

You can model the class structure as follows.

**Model classes for API 1:**

```
public class Api1Response
{ 
    public string RandomProperty2 { get; set; }
    public  AppBasic Application { get; set; }  
}

public class AppBasic
{
    public Page page { get; set; }
    public int members_total { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public DateTime created { get; set; }
    public int members_active { get; set; }
    public IList<undefined> fields { get; set; }
    public IList<Members> members { get; set; }
    public Error error { get; set; }
}
```

**Model classes for API 2:**

```
public class Api2Response
{ 
    public bool RandomProperty2 { get; set; }
    public  AppDetail Application { get; set; }  
}


public class AppDetail {
    public int message_id { get; set; }
    public DateTime send_at { get; set; }
    public int recipients { get; set; }
    public double cost { get; set; }
    public int sms { get; set; }
    public Delivery_stats delivery_stats { get; set; }
    public Error error { get; set; }
}
```